# Strong Type Data Set : Override column get : set

Tags: c#, xsd, strongly-typed-dataset

we are using data sets as our data access layer.
currently there are some columns that store encrypted data.

using CLR i was able to create an SQL function for decryption of the data in a select but in discussion we have determined that to be a security risk.

what i am looking to do is to either

1. override the get/set of the data table column so that when on the get it will un encrypt the value
   and return a readable string and on the set will encrypt the data.
2. or do something with the table adapter so that on the select / update would do the same as above.

Comment: is it possible to extend the table adapter in such a way that i could handle a on fill or on get? similar to http://forums.asp.net/t/1152173.aspx/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to create an extension methods for this task:

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static void SetEncryptColumn(this DataSetType.DataTableRow row, string value)
        {
            row.Encrypt = EncryptValue(value);
        }

        public static string GetEncryptColumn(this DataSetType.DataTableRow row)
        {
            return DecryptValue(row.Encrypt);
        }
    }   
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: have considered this, was really hopping there would be a way to have something like get{return DecryptValue(value)}

Comment: i do have an extension method for the strings already so i can say table.value.encrypt/decrypt() and get a return. the nature of what i am trying to do is place the decryption in the table adapter on fill or on get of data from DB. thanks of the reply!

Answer (score 0):

Typed DataTables are partial classes. While you can't override a property, you can add more methods in another file that will encrypt on set and decrypt on get, storing the values in the original properties.

Comment: any reference material or example you could provide?

Comment: Typed DataSets are partial classes, but I don't see 'partial' keyword in generated strongly typed row definition.

Comment: in visual studio 2012 pro .net 4.5 dataset, I do see something like
public partial class xyzRow : global::System.Data.DataRow {